# Gradle dependencies exclude

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, build.gradle, firebase-analytics

For some reason I have using java 1.7 to compile my project, but I'm facing duplicate entry error when compile the project. Below is my dependencies tree that showing the duplicate.

```
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:10.2.0
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0 (x)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:10.2.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0 (x)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:10.2.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0 (x)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.0 (x)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.0 (x)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.0 (x)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0 (x)
```

I have tried to add exclude when I compile the firebase-analytics libs, but it looks like only the first layer will be excluded, and not all. Can anyone help?

```
compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:10.2.0'){
exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-basement:10.2.0'
}
```

dependencies block:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-basement'
    }
    compile fileTree(dir: "${rootProject.projectDir}/android-libs", include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.10"
}
```

Comment: Post the dependencies block from your app build.gradle file.

Comment: BTW, there are newer version available for: firebase library: 10.2.1 and gson: 2.8.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to use configuration-wide exclusion as follows:

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-basement'
}
```

Or just exlude it from compile configuration only:

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-basement'
}
```

Comment: What is the **configurations{ }** block?  I think we can do this in **compile { }** block.

Comment: I think **compile(xxxx){}** is more local.